# using subset but old variables still left

Tags: r, subset

I am working with a data set, which is basically daily usage data (let's just say variable X and Y) by different cities (about 150 cities). I have created a subset of data for only specific cities, choosing just 3 of the 150 cities.
Then when I do `tapply` by cities, I get means for 3 cities but also get NA for all other 147 cities that was in the data set. I am using the below coding

```
df<-read.csv(...)
df_sub<-subset(df,df$City==1|df$City==3|df$City==19)
X_Breakdown<-tapply(X,df_sub$City, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
Print(X_Breakdown)
```

Which gives me:

```
                    City 1                         City 2 
                        15                             NA 
                    City 3                         City 4 
                        12                             NA 
                    City 5                         City 6 
                        NA                             NA
```

Hope you get the idea. I would like to get a dataset that only contains the 3 cities that I'm interested in.

It seems that the set of variables is encoded in R, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You can simplify your `subset` usage: `subset(df, City %in% c(1,3,19))`.

Answer (score 2):

`City` is most likely a factor:

```
fac <- factor(1:2,levels=1:3)
tapply(1:2,fac,mean)
# 1  2  3 
# 1  2 NA
```

Use `droplevels`:

```
tapply(1:2,droplevels(fac),mean)
#1 2 
#1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original data is `df` (not tested)

using `subset` as @Roland:

```
df_sub<-subset(df, City %in% c(1,3,19))
```

using `ddply` from `plyr package` instead of `tapply`

```
require(plyr)
X_Breakdown<-ddply(df_sub, .(City), summarize, meancity=mean(City))
```

Note: It would be best if you give us a sample data.